# Finding successive <br /> elements, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Imagine that I have this HTML snippet:

```
<div></div>
<br />
<div></div>
<br />
<img src='' alt='' />
<p></p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div></div>
<a href=''></a>
<br />
```

Which has no definite rule at all. The only thing I know, is that **3** consecutive `<br />` elements exist somewhere. Now, I need to find the **three consecutive `<br />` elements** using jQuery, and remove anything after them.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('br + br + br').nextAll().remove();
```

If there are potential text nodes to be removed, do this:

```
var el = $('br + br + br')[0],
    nxt;

while( nxt = el.nextSibling ) { 
    el.parentNode.removeChild( nxt );
}
```

Or with more jQuery:

```
var el = $('br + br + br')[0],
    nxt;

while( nxt = el.nextSibling ) { 
    $( nxt ).remove();
}
```

Comment: Or better ... `.nextUntil()` ? !

Comment: @roXon: Hmmm... I interpreted the question to require the removal of everything that comes after the 3 consecutive `br` elements.